# when i scroll down viewController shaking

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

[image]

Hello guys ,I have problem when i try scrolling down my viewcontroller shaking ,i couldn't find error.In other view controller haven't errors like this...
How i can fix it?

```
    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    setupBaseElement(for: view, customView: personInfoView)
    setupViews()
    setupSignals()
    view.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
```

Comment: If you are using a tableview or something, have you set estimatedHeightForRowAt? This should be the same height as the cells.

Comment: if you are using tableview  try to use the delegate estimated Height For Row At IndexPath method  and return same value as row height

Comment: i don't use tableView or collectionView(

Comment: this kind of issue will come when your scroll view is the first object in hierarchy. Try to add a dummy view with size 0, 0.  above the scroll view and give scrolview top constraint from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you're scrolling down past the bottom offset there, and that's the cause of your issue, but. If it is, you could try setting:

```
scrollView.bounces = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the bottom constraint layout of my scroll view to be relative to the Safe Area instead of its superview and that fixed this issue in my case.